# Error with JSP Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, eclipse-mars

I am working on JSP using eclipse mars with tomcat 8, when I run my server it sometimes shows the port is being by another program and when I change it it then shows Server tomcat at localhost failed to start, 'Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.

My console looks like this:

```
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule     begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting         property 
'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:try1' did not find a matching     property.
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.11.1
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:                 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b14
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:             /Users/apple/Desktop/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -    Dcatalina.base=/Users/apple/Desktop/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.s    erver.core/tmp0
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -    Dwtp.deploy=/Users/apple/Desktop/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.serv    er.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/apple/Downloads/tomcat-    juli.jar
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener     lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal     performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:     /Users/apple/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Jav    a/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool     getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9181"]
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool     getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 948 ms
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService     startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more

Nov 10, 2015 12:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/try1]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
```

Comment: Tomcat listens on several ports for various services.  Likely you are only change one of the ports.  Are you on Windows or Linux?  I would try and find out if you have a tomcat instance running that needs to be killed.

Comment: Is this the entire log output?